# App not working normally on Nexus 10

Tags: android

i am facing a strange problem(it may seem illogical, i am facing it!)

The problem is this part of code working well for all device but not working on my client's device NEXUS 10.
The Code is:

```
    Chronometer Timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.practicePageTimer);
    Timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if("00:30".equals(Timer.getText()))
            {
                Timer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowtimer);
            }
            else if("01:00".equals(Timer.getText()))
            {
                Timer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redtimer);
            }
        }

    });
```

It should change the background on "00:30" to yellow and on "01:00" to red, but it is not doing its job on nexus 10. I have tested it on Xperia S, Its working fine.
Please help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: Please copy paste the code, don't type it again (I am just saying because the first line has a typo that can't work at all: `Chornometer`) - have you tried to log the `Timer.getText()`?

Comment: yes, i already have check it, it is working on xperia s, but not working on nexus 10(My client is testing it on nexus 10).

Comment: please show the log you created with `Timer.getText()` in your `onChronometerTick()`

Comment: there're some discussions on xxhdpi for the nexus 10 (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nexus+10+xxhdpi&aq=0&oq=nexus+10+xxh&aqs=chrome.1.57j0.4676j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) maybe you should give a try to add redtimer and yellowtimer on that folder.

Comment: @Budius, i have put these images in default drawable folder, it is accessing all other drawables perfectly then why red and yellowTimer image are inaccessible for him.(not make any sense)

Comment: I agree it makes no sense, but some stuff in life is a bit weird. Alex suggestion on the answer below sounds quite reasonable too, maybe calling getFormat() should drop some light in the issue.

Comment: @Budius, yes I am also considering that Alex answer will help me out, I am trying it, let see what happen?? Thanks for answer :)

Comment: It would be so easy if the OP would just log the result of `getText()`...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, i have logged it on my device it is returning the string in this "00:30" format which is ok, But The problem is arising on My client Side, how can i get the log result when he is test the app on his side, Hope you got the point! Thanks

Comment: The key is to log on the nexus 10. For example you can append the getText value to a StringBuffer (with some format, every tick in a new line) and add a send via e-mail button (and build an e-mail body from code) to the GUI and ask your user to send the log after the app run at least 1:30.

Comment: Therefore apps like "Log collector" are available...

Comment: Any update on this? Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for your interest, i am working on it, will send the apk after adding one new module, he will test it, then i will update you about it. Thanks

Comment: @Alex its solved, Nexus chronometer starts from 0:00 not from 00:00, This was the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the Nexus 10's Locale is other then what you expect and the returned value simply doesn't match.
"By default it will display the current timer value in the form "MM:SS" or "H:MM:SS", or you can use setFormat(String) to format the timer value into an arbitrary string. " 
Try to set the format using setFromat("MM:SS"); Maybe helps.

Comment: Edited: I just read the comments above, so i'm not sure what is the problem, but i'm guessing your problem can be with the IF statement. Try to put some logging because it's hard to figure out without any clue.

Comment: I have place the resource file in Default folder, In Case, if It is not finding the resource file then it should crash, but i just work well without doing anything.

Comment: Try to log somehow the ticks (getText() ) and if the code enter to the ifs or not.